# Why is the following LaTeX code invalid?

Tags: math-mode, errors

I am trying to compile a document using lyx and the following line:

```
$Encrypted(k_\left\{subcontractor,airplane\right\}, softwareBytes | HMAC(softwareBytes))$
```

gives an error as if the first and second squiggly brackets are not closed even though running the same code [here](https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) displays the intended output.

Why?

**Edit:**

I've added the subscript braces:

```
$Encrypted(k_{\left\{subcontractor,airplane{\right\}}}, softwareBytes | HMAC(softwareBytes))$
```

In the online editor it works. In lyx the following errors are given:

```
Missing } inserted.
Extra }, or forgotten $
```

Comment: You have to use braces for subscripts: `_{\left\{ \right\}}`

Comment: I have added them but the syntax error persists. The code is still valid in the online editor.

Comment: Now it looks like you have an extra pair of braces around the `\right\}`

Comment: Yep, that was it.

Comment: Maybe you could be interested in `\text{subcontractor}` from `amsmath` package.

Comment: not the cause of the error (which is missing braces around the subscript) but never use the math italic font for words, it is designed with wide sidebearings to make adjacent letters look like a product of variables and _not_ a word

Comment: please do not edit the question to contain the answer, the answer should be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the error message is due to missing braces around the subscript, but other non-reported errors are use of math-italic for words, and use of `\left`,`\right` in this context also `\mid` gives perhaps better spacing than `|`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$\mathrm{Encrypted}(k_{\{ \mathrm{subcontractor},\mathrm{airplane}\}}, \mathrm{softwareBytes} \mid \mathrm{HMAC}(\mathrm{softwareBytes}))$

\end{document}
```

Comment: May be `\operatorname{Encrypted}` and `\operatorname{\textsc{hmac}}` might be liked (or declaring `\DeclareMathOperator\Encrypted{Encrypted}` and `\DeclareMathOperator\HMAC{\textsc{hmac}}`).

Comment: @Manuel I wondered about doing that but "one thing at a time" :-)